# How to correctly move ownership from raw pointer to std::unique_ptr?

Tags: c++, smart-pointers

My approach is:

```
class SomeClass
{
    std::vector<std::unique_ptr<MyObject>> myObjects;
public:
    void takeOwnership(MyObject *nowItsReallyMyObject)
    {
        myObjects.emplace_back(std::move(nowItsReallyMyObject));
    }
};
```

Am I doing everything correctly or are there any better solutions?

Comment: You don't need the `std::move`.

Comment: There's no point calling `std::move` on a primitive type (a pointer)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `move` is redundant.

Myself, I'd do this:

```
void takeOwnership(std::unique_ptr<MyObject> nowItsReallyMyObject)
{
    myObjects.emplace_back(std::move(nowItsReallyMyObject));
}
```

because I would want to move the `unique_ptr` ownership semantics as far "out" as possible.

I might write this utility function:

```
template<class T>
std::unique_ptr<T> wrap_in_unique( T* t ) {
  return std::unique_ptr<T>(t);
}
```

so callers can:

```
foo.takeOwnership(wrap_in_unique(some_ptr));
```

but even better, then can push the borders of `unique_ptr` semantics out as far as they reasonably can.

I might even do:

```
template<class T>
std::unique_ptr<T> wrap_in_unique( T*&& t ) {
  auto* tmp = t;
  t = 0;
  return std::unique_ptr<T>(tmp);
}
template<class T>
std::unique_ptr<T> wrap_in_unique( std::unique_ptr<T> t ) {
  return std::move(t);
}
```

which lets callers transition their `T*` into `unique_ptr`s easier.  All of their `T*`->`unique_ptr<T>` is now wrapped in a `std::move`, and zeros the source pointer.

So if they had

```
struct I_am_legacy {
  T* I_own_this = 0;
  void GiveMyStuffTo( SomeClass& sc ) {
    sc.takeOwnership( wrap_in_unique(std::move(I_own_this)) );
  }
};
```

the code can be transformed into:

```
struct I_am_legacy {
  std::unique_ptr<T> I_own_this;
  void GiveMyStuffTo( SomeClass& sc ) {
    sc.takeOwnership( wrap_in_unique(std::move(I_own_this)) );
  }
};
```

and it still compiles and works the same.  (Other interaction with `I_own_this` may have to change, but part of it will already be unique_ptr compatible).

Answer (score 4):

You should accept the `unique_ptr` from the get-go:

```
class SomeClass
{
    std::vector<std::unique_ptr<MyObject>> myObjects;
public:
    // tells the world you 0wNz this object
    void takeOwnership(std::unique_ptr<MyObject> myObject)
    {
        myObjects.push_back(std::move(myObject));
    }
};
```

This way you make it clear you take ownership and you also help other programmers to avoid using raw pointers.

Further reading: [CppCoreGuidelines R.32](https://github.com/isocpp/CppCoreGuidelines/blob/master/CppCoreGuidelines.md#Rr-uniqueptrparam)